# MySQL : How to link a stored procedure to a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I link a stored procedure to a temporary table?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is the question how do you reference a temporary table in a stored procedure? I don't know what you mean by "link".

Answer (score 0):

I had a database created named Multi. All the attributes of table registration are copied into the stored procedure. In this you cannot insert from stored procedure. This is just creating a stored procedure and giving it something to hold.
[This is the example of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YynQc.jpg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)